# Non trivial automorphism that fixes subfield

Tags: galois-theory

I feel like this should be obvious but if I have a field extension $L/K$ and a proper subfield, say $M$ with $L/M/K$, then is there always a non-trivial automorphism that fixes M?

So then, for example, if I wanted to show $M$ is in fact the whole of $L$ then I would just need to show there are no automorphisms fixing $M$?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked on your text notes or book? There should be a result in there regarding (something similar to) this.

Comment: I have that this is true if $L/K$ is Galois because if no then $M$ would have to be $K$?

Comment: Take an irreducible monic polynomial $m(x)$ in $M[x]$ with degree larger than $2$ and let $\alpha,\beta$ be two distinct roots of $m(x)$ (note that they are not in $M$). Consider $M(\alpha)$ and $M(\beta)$. Let $n$ be the degree of $m(x)$. Given $\lambda\in M(\alpha)$, there exist certain (unique actually) scalars $\lambda _0, \ldots ,\lambda_{n-1}$ in $M$, such that $\lambda=\lambda_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1}+\ldots +\lambda_1 \alpha +\lambda _0$. The map $f\colon M(\alpha)\to M(\beta), \lambda \mapsto \lambda_{n-1}\beta^{n-1}+\ldots +\lambda_1 \beta +\lambda _0$ should have the desired property.

Comment: The problem is there's no reason why $\alpha$ or $\beta$ should be in $L$ and I'm guessing this is something you require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would work if the extension  $L/M$  is Galois. Here are two examples that show that you need normal and separable:

$$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})/\mathbb{Q}\\
\mathbb{F}_p(t^{1/p}) /\mathbb{F}_p(t) 
$$