# Finding an automorphism of $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$ that fixes two given elements

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $u,v,w \in \mathbb{C}(x,y)-\mathbb{C}$.

> Is it possible to find an automorphism $f$ of $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$ that 
>   fixes $u$ and $v$, and not fixes $w$? namely,
>   $f(u)=u, f(v)=v, f(w)\neq w$.

Perhaps [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1101139/non-trivial-automorphism-that-fixes-subfield) is relevant.

**Remark:** If $\mathbb{C}(u,v) \subseteq \mathbb{C}(u,v)(w)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$
is Galois of order $>1$, then my question has a positive answer: One can take any $f \neq 1$ from the Galois group.

Any comments are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no in general.

For example, if $w=u+v$ then $f(w)=f(u)+f(v)=u+v=w$.

Same way, since $f$ fixes $\mathbb Q$, any $w \in \mbox{Span}_{\mathbb Q} \{ 1, u, v \}$ is a counter example.

You might need to throw in the condition that $1,u, v, w$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$ or some algebraic independence condition, if you want to get a positive result.

**Edit:** As Alex pointed, linear independence is not enough. For example if $w=P(u,v)$ for some polynomial $P$, then $f(u)=u, f(v)=v$ implies $f(w)=w$.

Comment: I don't think linear independence is enough, e.g. with $u = x, v = y$ and $w$ anything. Maybe algebraic independence is enough.

Comment: @AlexWertheim Thank you, added a comment. Your example is basically the same as saying $w$ is an arbitrary polynomial in $u,v$ :)

Comment: Thank you both. Even before considering $w$, I do not understand why there should exist an automorphism of $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$ that fixes the given $u$ and $v$. (I have read soemwhere that an automorphism of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ fixes an element of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, but I am asking for the 'converse' in $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$).

Comment: @user237522 The identity function fixes both $u,v$. Now, if you want non-trivial examples, define $K=\mathbb C(u,v)$ and $L= \mathbb C (x,y)$. Then you have a field extension $K \subseteq L$. If they are equal, then, it is trivial to see that the identity function is the only automorphism which fixes $u,v$. Otherwise, the automorphisms of $\mathbb C(x,y)$ which fix $\mathbb C, u,v$ are exactly the definition of elements in the Galois group $G(K/L)$. So you are basically looking for non-trivial elements in this group, and the theory sais that this is non-trivial under pretty mild assumptions.

Comment: Yes. But I am not sure I am familiar with those 'mild assumptions' that you hint. What I know is that if $u,v \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{C}$, then $\mathbb{C}(u,v) \subseteq \mathbb{C}(x,y)$ is finite and separable. (It is finite since $\mathbb{C}(u,v)$ and $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$ has transcendence degree two over $\mathbb{C}$. Separability is obvious).

Comment: An example. If I am not wrong, the following is a special case where my question has a positive answer: $u=x$, $v=y^5$ and arbitrary $w \in \mathbb{C}(x,y)-\mathbb{C}(x,y^5)$ (for example, $w=y$). $\mathbb{C}(x,y^5) \subsetneq \mathbb{C}(x,y)$ is Galois of degree five. So we have four automorphisms fixing $u$ and $v$ and not fixing $w$.

Comment: @N.S., you have written: "...and the theory says that this is non-trivial under pretty mild assumptions".  Please what are the mild assumptions?

Comment: @user237522 If $w$ is algebaric over $\mathbb C(u,v)$, and its minimal polynomial splits, then $\mathbb C(u,v,w)$ is Galois over $\mathbb C(u,v)$, and you can find an automorphism of this smaller field with the desired properties. It would not surprise me if by Zorn Lemma you cannot extend this automorphism to the entire $\mathbb C( x,y)$. All you need is that the minimal polynomial of $w$ splits.

Comment: Also, if $w$ is transcendent over $\mathbb C(u,v)$, I think that you can construct an automorphism of $C(u,v,w)$ by sending $w \to \frac{1}{w}$

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments.(Of course, in the algebraic case you assume that $\mathbb{C}(u,v) \subsetneq \mathbb{C}(u,v,w)$, since otherwise, as you and @AlexWertheim mentioned above, an automorphism that fixes $u$ and $v$ also fixes $w \in \mathbb{C}(u,v)$). I like your idea when $w$ is transcendental over $\mathbb{C}(u,v)$.